# Get the position of an animationClip at a given time in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to retrieve the Transform/Position of an animationClip at a given time/frame.

I can actually set an animationClip to a given time with animationClip.SampleAnimation()(https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationClip.SampleAnimation.html)

Therefore I could eventually create a clone, put it on a specific frame and get his position, but it would be too heavy for each frame.

If you have any solutions, or maybe some functions that I didn't see I would be glad.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution, it takes a lot of process, but as it's done only in Editor it doesn't affect the game.
I am getting the curve of the animationclip and I store 10 position, each corresponding to 10% of the animation.

For this I need to compute each x, y and z axis curves :

```
void OnValidate()
{
    //Check if we are in the Editor, and the animationClip is getting change
    if (Application.isEditor && !Application.isPlaying && previousClip != animationClip)
    {
        previousClip = animationClip;
        m_checkPoints = new Vector3[10];
        int index = 0;

        //Taking the curves form the animation clip
        AnimationCurve curve;
        var curveBindings = AnimationUtility.GetCurveBindings(animationClip);

        //Going into each curves
        foreach (var curveBinding in curveBindings)
        {
            //Checking curve's name, as we only need those about the position
            if (curveBinding.propertyName == "m_LocalPosition.x")
                index = 0;
            else if (curveBinding.propertyName == "m_LocalPosition.y")
                index = 1;
            else if (curveBinding.propertyName == "m_LocalPosition.z")
                index = 2;
            else
                continue;

            //Get the curveform the editor
            curve = AnimationUtility.GetEditorCurve(animationClip, curveBinding);

            for (float i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                //Evaluate the curves at a given time
                m_checkPoints[(int)i][index] = curve.Evaluate(animationClip.length * (i / 10f));
            }
        }
    }
}
```